# Equivalence of two different definitions of $s'$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, schwartz-space

I was reading [Treves book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1483210197) and, on page 527, defined the following objects. A sequence $\tau = (\tau_{p})_{p\in \mathbb{Z}^{d}}$ is of slowly growing if there exists an integer $k \ge 0$ and a constant $C \ge 0$ such that:
$$ (1+|p|)^{-k}|\tau_{p}| \le C $$
for every $p \in \mathbb{Z}^{d}$. The space of all slowly growing sequences is $s'$.

However, I came across a different definition of $s'$ which is the following: $s'$ is the space of all sequences $\tau = (\tau_{p})_{p\in \mathbb{Z}^{d}}$ satisfying:
$$\sum_{p\in \mathbb{Z}^{d}}(1+|p|)^{k}|\tau_{p}| < +\infty$$
for some integer $k \ge 0$. I'm trying to prove that this spaces are the same. I already proved one implication, which is:

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose the second condition holds. Then, because $(1+|p|)^{-k}\le (1+|p|)^{k}$ for every $p \in \mathbb{Z}^{d}$, then:
$$(1+|p|)^{-k}|\tau_{p}| \le (1+|p|)^{k}|\tau_{p}| \le \sum_{p\in \mathbb{Z}^{d}}(1+|p|)^{k}|\tau_{p}| < +\infty$$
and the first condition follows. But I'm really stuck proving the converse. Can anyone help me please?

**NOTE:** I tried to find some nice references on these sequences spaces (Treves book introduces it briefly) and its alternative representations. So, any good reference is also welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant $\sum_{p\in \mathbb{Z}^{d}}(1+|p|)^{-k}|\tau_{p}| < +\infty$ which implies that $(1+|p|)^{-k}|\tau_{p}|<C$, conversely if $(1+|p|)^{-k}|\tau_{p}|<C$ then $\sum_{p\in \mathbb{Z}^{d}}(1+|p|)^{-k-d-1}|\tau_{p}| < +\infty$. This space of polynomially bounded sequences $S'(\Bbb{Z}^d)$ is the dual of the space of fast decreasing sequence $S(\Bbb{Z}^d)$, ie. the map $x\to \sum_k x_k \tau_k$ is a well-defined linear functional continuous in the $S(\Bbb{Z}^d)$ topology.

Comment: You mean I should change $k \to -k$ in my second condition? I thought it was defined with $+k$.

Comment: Well this explains a lot.

Comment: Also, you seem to be using the fact that $\sum_{p\in \mathbb{Z}^{d}}(1+|p|)^{-d-1}$ is convergent. Is there an easy way to see it?

Comment: $ \int_{[1,\infty)^d} |x|^{-d-1}dx$ converges by radial change of variable